# Swift - index out of range while trying to automatically fill an array

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

So, i'm new to swift and trying to do a loop calculation which I'll describe

I have an array which already has a couple of elements on it
so I declared a variable to perform a loop that has a value equal to 2, (`i=2`)
then, from another equation i got an int number which defines the final number of elements on the array (say, `limit = 19`)

So my current code looks like this:

```
//I declare my array
var velocityArray: [Double] = []
var densityArray: [Double] = []
//first and second element appended after declaring by another function

while i <= limit
{
var velocity = initialflow/(densityArray[i - 1] * area)
velocityArray.append(velocity)

i = i + 1
}
```

So when I try to run this code, I get an "index out of range" error on the line where the variable velocity is calculated.

If I declare my variable limit to be equal to 2, so that both the loop variable 'i' and the 'limit' variable are equal. it turns out it runs fine, it appends the element correctly as the third element of the array, but if I try to perform a loop it just won't work, it might be a dumb question, but i just can't seem to figure it out by myself.

Thank you all for reading and helping out, cheers.

Comment: "first and second element appended after declaring by another function" Maybe, but you need to _show_ that. _Show your code_. As far as the code you've actually shown is concerned, none of your code ever gives `densityArray` any elements. So it is empty. So `densityArray[0]` or anything else is out of bounds. And we have no reason to know that that ever changes, have we?

Comment: As @matt said, you need to show the code where you change the `densityArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're indexing your array with `i` which is <= limit. Anyway, you should check array count for any index before accessing it, beside your  `densityArray` is empty:

```
while i >= 0 && i < densityArray.count
{
    var velocity = initialflow/(densityArray[i] * area)
    velocityArray.append(velocity)
    i = i + 1
 }
```